# Good system for a sci-fi homebrew.

Tags: science-fiction

So, I am in the mood to make a sci-fi tabletop RP in a custom universe, but do not know any good systems to use for it. I am used to DND 5E and Edge of the Empire, but I do not know if either those are friendly for homebrew (at least for sci-fi, in the case of DND 5e)

So, I was wondering if there are other alternatives.

Comment: I think you might be able to turn this into an on-topic question by describing your universe and intended game a little better, and asking some specific questions about how to adapt it to 5E/EotE. Unfortunately, any question here has to be answerable, and questions which look like "what system is good for ____" are off-topic because of that.